# Change auto indentation of comments

Tags: r, emacs, ess

It has been a while that my emacs+ess does very strange on auto indentation of comment:

If I type a comment start with a single `#` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The line is pushed to the right 40 spaces. I have to go back and delete those spaces and move the cursor down by using down arrow key. This is very inconvenient. And it happens only while I am in ESS mode. However, it does not happen if I start the line with double `#` or disable `electric-indent-mode`

How do I fix this?

Comment: Read the ESS documentation. That is a _feature_.

Comment: No I vaguely remember I read it before :D